# Insert into a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, syntax-error

I have a string -

```
insert into staging_table values('AC','36569','SL','4950 W NEWPORT','CHICAGO');insert into staging_table values('AC','36569','SL','4950 W NEWPORT','CHICAGO');
```

I have a worksheet TEST and it has 2 columns `SQL,flg`.

Data under these columns is  `" ",1`

How can I write an update statement to update the value of column `SQL` where `flg` is 1 with above string.

The problem I am facing is that the single quotes present in the string, when I execute the update statement I get a syntax error ...Please advise.

Comment: What if you try this: `insert into staging_table (SQL) Values("'AC','36569','SL','4950 W NEWPORT','CHICAGO'") Where flg = 1` ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find cells with the value `" ",1` and replace the value `" ",1` with something else?

Comment: I am treating my worksheet TEST as a table, and first row has SQL and flg. so these will be the columns in my table TEST. UPDATE [TEST$] SET [SQL]=<the above string> WHERE [flg]=1

Comment: Do you try my suggestion above, Vikram. (I wrote the wrong Update syntax, but basically if you set your SQL statement inside double quotes, it may work for what you are trying to do? Especially if you are using VBA to do so.

Comment: The value I am using to update column SQL of the worksheet TEST is "insert into staging_table values('AC','36569','SL','4950 W NEWPORT','CHICAGO');insert into staging_table values('AC','36569','SL','4950 W NEWPORT','CHICAGO');"

Comment: Do you surround that whole text with double quotes... so it's `Update [TEST] SET {SQL] = "insert into staging_table values('AC','36569','SL','4950 W NEWPORT','CHICAGO');insert into staging_table values('AC','36569','SL','4950 W NEWPORT','CHICAGO');" WHERE [flg] = 1;`

Comment: Yes , If I do that I get an error ...

Comment: try putting quotes around the first and last `'` in both sets of `Values(...)` statements.

Comment: Double-up the ' to escape them for SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a string value containing single-quotes in a SQL insert/update, you need to escape the ' by doubling them up

E.g.

`...values('AC','36569',...`

should be

`...values(''AC'',''36569'',...`